# Could not install Apache Beam SDK from a wheel: could not find a Beam SDK wheel among staged files, proceeding to install SDK from source tarball

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, python-3.8

i work on a google cloud environment where i don't have internet access. I'm trying to launch a dataflow job passing it the sdk like this:

```bash
python wordcount.py --no_use_public_ip --sdk_location "<basepath>/dist/package-import-0.0.2.tar.gz"
```

I generated package-import-0.0.2.tar.gz with this setup.py

```py
    import setuptools

    setuptools.setup(
        name='package-import',
        version='0.0.2',
        install_requires=[
            'apache-beam==2.43.0',
            'cachetools==4.2.4',
            'certifi==2022.12.7',
            'charset-normalizer==2.1.1',
            'cloudpickle==2.2.0',
            'crcmod==1.7',
            'dill==0.3.1.1',
            'docopt==0.6.2',
            'fastavro==1.7.0',
            'fasteners==0.18',
            'google-api-core==2.11.0',
            'google-apitools==0.5.31',
            'google-auth==2.15.0',
            'google-auth-httplib2==0.1.0',
            'google-cloud-bigquery==3.4.1',
            'google-cloud-bigquery-storage==2.13.2',
            'google-cloud-bigtable==1.7.3',
            'google-cloud-core==2.3.2',
            'google-cloud-datastore==1.15.5',
            'google-cloud-dlp==3.10.0',
            'google-cloud-language==1.3.2',
            'google-cloud-pubsub==2.13.11',
            'google-cloud-pubsublite==1.6.0',
            'google-cloud-recommendations-ai==0.7.1',
            'google-cloud-spanner==3.26.0',
            'google-cloud-videointelligence==1.16.3',
            'google-cloud-vision==1.0.2',
            'google-crc32c==1.5.0',
            'google-resumable-media==2.4.0',
            'googleapis-common-protos==1.57.1',
            'grpc-google-iam-v1==0.12.4',
            'grpcio==1.51.1',
            'grpcio-status==1.51.1',
            'hdfs==2.7.0',
            'httplib2==0.20.4',
            'idna==3.4',
            'numpy==1.22.4',
            'oauth2client==4.1.3',
            'objsize==0.5.2',
            'orjson==3.8.3',
            'overrides==6.5.0',
            'packaging==22.0',
            'proto-plus==1.22.1',
            'protobuf==3.20.3',
            'pyarrow==9.0.0',
            'pyasn1==0.4.8',
            'pyasn1-modules==0.2.8',
            'pydot==1.4.2',
            'pymongo==3.13.0',
            'pyparsing==3.0.9',
            'python-dateutil==2.8.2',
            'pytz==2022.7',
            'regex==2022.10.31',
            'requests==2.28.1',
            'rsa==4.9',
            'six==1.16.0',
            'sqlparse==0.4.3',
            'typing-extensions==4.4.0',
            'urllib3==1.26.13',
            'zstandard==0.19.0'
            ],
        packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
        )
```

but in dataflow log worker i have this error: Could not install Apache Beam SDK from a wheel: could not find a Beam SDK wheel among staged files, proceeding to install SDK from source tarball.
And then he tries to download it but since he doesn't have internet he can't

my biggest problem is that the google cloud environment doesn't access the internet so dataflow can't download what it needs. Do you know of a way to pass it an sdk_location?

Comment: Do you want running the `Beam` job with `Dataflow` runner ?

Comment: yes i used this:    
 pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(
        pipeline_args,
        runner="DataFlowRunner",
        project="<my-project>",
        job_name="testbigquery2",
        temp_location="<my-bucket>",
        region="<regione>"
        )
    return p

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to internet from your environement, I thought on a solution based on a `Docker` image.

**- Workers**

`Dataflow` `Python` can use a `Docker` [image](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-custom-containers) in the execution phase while creating the workers.

In this image `Docker` you can install all the needed packages in the container and publish it to Container Registry, example :

```
FROM apache/beam_python3.8_sdk:2.44.0

# Pre-built python dependencies  
RUN pip install lxml
# Pre-built other dependencies  
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get dist-upgrade \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends ffmpeg
      
# Set the entrypoint to the Apache Beam SDK launcher.
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/apache/beam/boot"]
```

In the `Dataflow` job, you have to specify 2 program arguments to use the image :

- experiments
- sdk_container_image

```bash
python -m apache_beam.examples.wordcount \
  --input=INPUT_FILE \
  --output=OUTPUT_FILE \
  --project=PROJECT_ID \
  --region=REGION \
  --temp_location=TEMP_LOCATION \
  --runner=DataflowRunner \
  --disk_size_gb=DISK_SIZE_GB \
  --experiments=use_runner_v2 \
  --sdk_container_image=$IMAGE_URI
```

**- Runner from your google environment**

Your Google environment executing the job needs also to have the packages installed in order to be able to instantiate the job.

You need to find a way to install the packages in the machines and your environment. If you can use the same `Docker` image used for `Dataflow` workers and execution phase, it would be perfect.

Comment: ok but if i don't use --sdk_location but use your command the dataflow job not start and i have this error:

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7ffff30c8dc0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/apache-beam/


I have this error because i don't have internet access

Comment: What is the google cloud env ?

Comment: This don't work beacuse docker needs internet. I solved using an internal proxy that allowed me to access the internet. In the command added this --no_use_public_ip and i set no_proxy="metadata.google.internal,www.googleapis.com,dataflow.googleapis.com,bigquery.googleapis.com"

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved using an internal proxy that allowed me to access the internet. In the command added this --no_use_public_ip and i set no_proxy="metadata.google.internal,www.googleapis.com,dataflow.googleapis.com,bigquery.googleapis.com" thanks